Finite simple $\pi$-groups
$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$Let $\pi$ be a finite set of primes.  A finite group $G$ is a $\pi$-group if all primes dividing $|G|$ lie in $\pi$.  Is it true that there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of simple $\pi$-groups?
We could try to approach this using the classification, as follows.  There are only finitely many sporadic groups, so we can ignore them.  It is clear that there are only finitely many prime cyclic groups or alternating groups that are $\pi$-groups.  For $\SL(n,p^v)$ to be a $\pi$-group we must have $p\in\pi$, and $n$ must be less than the smallest prime outside $\pi$, so there are only finitely many possibilities for the pair $(p,n)$.  It is not so obvious what to say about $v$, although the critical case seems to be when $v$ is also prime, and experiment suggests that the largest prime factor of $|\SL(n,p^v)|$ grows very rapidly with $v$ in that case.  The story should be similar for the simple quotient $\PSL(n,p^v)$ and for other families of Lie type.  However, it would be more satisfactory to have a proof independent of the classification; I do not know whether that is at all plausible.

Surely you know this, but for the benefit of others, let me point out that there is a simple (ha ha) argument that the only finite simple $p$-groups are $\mathbb{Z}/p$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012626

@SamHopkins Indeed, and Burnside's $p^aq^b$ Theorem says that the only simple ${p,q}$-groups are $C_p$ and $C_q$, so there is no problem until $|\pi|\geq 3$.

I would not be optimistic about proving this without CFSG. In a positive direction (from your point of view), H. Wielandt proved without the full classification that there are only a few primes $p$ such that there are simple ${2,3,p }$ groups ( from memory,I think $17$ is the largest such $p$), but even that made use of John Thompson's classification of minimal simple groups.

I suppose I should have said ``non-Abelian simple ${2,3,p }$-groups"!.

This is observed to be true in the remark on page 51 of Mazurov, "The set of orders of elements in a finite group" (Algebra and Logic 33 no 1, 1994) using the classification together with Zsigmondy's theorem. I strongly suspect that trying to find a proof without almost all of the classification is pretty hopeless.

Thanks! The title was slightly wrong so I have fixed it, and added a link.
